# Prompt for copy/move in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a package that'll hook into Explorer and - on a drag and drop of a file - prompt each time time with separate Copy and Move buttons. It'll need to support Windows 7 and higher. Anyone heard of such a thing?

Comment: Use the right mouse button instead of the left when dragging a file